# Why is this xamarin android menu text not showing?

Tags: android, colors, xamarin.android, styles, menuitem

I have a simple application in Xamarin Android but the menu items are not showing the text. I've played with themes, backgrounds, etc, to no avail. Since I can't see the text, I can't confirm if the text is missing or if the text is white on white.

Here's the screen shot:

[image: Screenshot of expanded menu]

Toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar"
     android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"
     />
```

Menu/Main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_rate"
         android:showAsAction="never"
         android:text="Rate Us!"
         android:orderInCategory="0"/>
   <item android:id="@+id/action_one"
         android:showAsAction="never"
         android:text="One"
         android:orderInCategory="1"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_blog"
         android:showAsAction="never"
         android:text="Blog"
         android:orderInCategory="2"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_about"
         android:showAsAction="never"
         android:text="About"
         android:orderInCategory="3"/>
    </menu>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
 // In OnCreate:
    var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    SetActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar.Title = ""

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.Top, menu);
            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Top of Main.axml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/Main">
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_gravity="top" />
```

Application section in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

And styles.xml - which probably contains unneeded stuff since I was troubleshooting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#000000</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I've tried using different themes, colors, etc and still can't make the text from the menu items show. Is there a way to control the background and text colors for the menu items?

Help me, Overflow Kenobi, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `android:text` to `android:title` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_rate"
         android:showAsAction="never"
         android:title="Rate Us!"
         android:orderInCategory="0"/>
   <item android:id="@+id/action_one"
         android:showAsAction="never"
          android:title="One"
         android:orderInCategory="1"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_blog"
         android:showAsAction="never"
          android:title="Blog"
         android:orderInCategory="2"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_about"
         android:showAsAction="never"
          android:title="About"
         android:orderInCategory="3"/>
    </menu>
```

[image]

Comment: That was it. Thank you!

Comment: Incidentally, I'm using a dark theme everywhere. How are you setting the background / theme  for the menu items? Mine comes up with white background, black text ( I removed the popuptheme from toolbar.xml)

Comment: I figured it out. 

<style name="MyDarkToolbarStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>